# How to make BottomNavigationView Menu in Uppercase?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I want to make BottomNavigationView Menu in UpperCase, How can i do that without using 3rd party library?

Here is my xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

And navigation.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:title="@string/title_home"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_deals"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_deals"
        android:title="@string/deals" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_myBookings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_bookings"
        android:title="@string/title_my_bookings" />

   <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more"
        android:title="@string/title_more" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

Create a style like this **`BottomNavigationViewStyle`**

```
<style name="BottomNavigationViewStyle">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

Than use like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    app:theme="@style/BottomNavigationViewStyle" />
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply this theme to your bottom navigation

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```